# Body background takes a while to load landing on the side .. how could I fix it?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

So the whole body background of my website has been manually inserted in my CSS code below , but occasionally , sometimes the background takes many seconds to load and I'll first see the DEFAULT while background and I think that would not look good at all .. Users need to see the whole intended background right away .. How can I fix that ?  Below is the part of the CSS code handling that.

```
body
    {
    background-image:url('/images/background.png');
        background-size:100%;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    }
```

Comment: Get a faster server? But seriously, what do you expect you'd be able to do? You could compress the image, but that's about it.

Comment: yes, make sure the size of `background.png` is small. maybe in 50~100kb. Anything bigger than that for a background is not recommended.

Comment: also try to use `repeat-x` and `repeat-y` wherever possible instead of using a big image, you can use a small one and repeat it as many times as you want :)

Comment: If you want to see the background right away , use a small size image of 2-10kb , that can be achieved with small patterns and images which have repetition in them . Optimize your image in photoshop .

Comment: There's no "fix" for speed. An alternative way would be adding a background-color. Then at least you don't see plain white background upon landing

Answer (score 0):

although it's considered bad practice to serve a large image on your home page (esp considering the powerful client side rendering options provided by html5 such as *svg/vector graphic rendering* (anything you can create on adobe illustrator can be served with trivial cost) and *canvas* along with the powerful [libraries](http://www.flotcharts.org/) that come with it) there are a few options that can help you:

1. **first time users:** Use CDNs (content delivery network) that cache static content at edge locations **ie** a hosting service like amazon's [cloud front](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/#common-use-cases) caches copies of your image in server farms all over the world.. when a first-time user visits your site.. it sends them the static content from a server farm nearest to them to cut latency.
2. **repeat users**: you can use [HTML 5 caching](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/). Although browsers are supposed to cache static content like your image by default.. it's unreliable and unpredictable. With html 5 caching, after the user has visited your site, html5 will cache that image so that the next time they come it will be served almost instantly.